# Are [telephone], [cellphone], [mobile-phones], and [phone] meta-tags for Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, meta-tags, burninate-request

None of these 4 tags [telephone](/questions/tagged/telephone) (x 45), [cellphone](/questions/tagged/cellphone) (x 82), [mobile-phones](/questions/tagged/mobile-phones) (x 341), [phone](/questions/tagged/phone) (x 1041) alone can give a hint about a programming question on Stack Overflow and these tags can’t work as the only tag on a question. I think with that definition these 4 become a [meta-tag](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/) for Stack Overflow and can be burninated.

Comment: +1 there's more specific tags which better apply to a lot of these questions like [tag:telephony], [tag:telecommunications], [tag:voip]